# Show that principal curvatures are the roots to the equation $\det([\text{II}]-\kappa[\text{I}])=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

> Show that principal curvatures are the roots to the equation $\det([\text{II}]-\kappa[\text{I}])=0$.

I know that since principals curvatures are the eigenvalues of matrix $[\text{L}]$ (Weingarton map), so have $\kappa^2 -2H\kappa+K=0$ since it's the characteristic polynomial. So apparently if we can show that $\det([\text{L}]-\kappa[\text{id}])=\det([\text{II}]-\kappa[\text{I}])$, then we win. But I don't see how this works. Probably I forgot some propositions from linear algebra? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Weingarten map $L$ and the fundamental forms are related by $\text{II} = L\cdot \text{I}$, so $$\det(\text{II} - \kappa \text{I}) = \det(L \cdot \text I- \kappa \text I) = \det (L-\kappa \text{id})\det(\text{I}).$$ Since I is non-degenerate, its determinant is nonzero.